# i have from my original dataframe obtained another two , how can i merge in a final one the columns that i need

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, rolling-computation

i have a table with 4 columns , from this data i obtained another 2 tables with some rolling averages from the original table. now i want to combine these 3 into a final table. but the indexes are not in order now and i cant do it. I just started to learn python , i have zero experience and i would really need all  the help i can get.

DF

```
+----+------------+-----------+------+------+
|    |     A      |     B     |  C   |  D   |
+----+------------+-----------+------+------+
|  1 | Home Team  | Away Team | Htgs | Atgs |
|  2 | dalboset   | sopot     | 1    | 2    |
|  3 | calnic     | resita    | 1    | 3    |
|  4 | sopot      | dalboset  | 2    | 2    |
|  5 | resita     | sopot     | 4    | 1    |
|  6 | sopot      | dalboset  | 2    | 1    |
|  7 | caransebes | dalboset  | 1    | 2    |
|  8 | calnic     | resita    | 1    | 3    |
|  9 | dalboset   | sopot     | 2    | 2    |
| 10 | calnic     | resita    | 4    | 1    |
| 11 | sopot      | dalboset  | 2    | 1    |
| 12 | resita     | sopot     | 1    | 2    |
| 13 | sopot      | dalboset  | 1    | 3    |
| 14 | caransebes | dalboset  | 2    | 2    |
| 15 | calnic     | resita    | 4    | 1    |
| 16 | dalboset   | sopot     | 2    | 1    |
| 17 | calnic     | resita    | 1    | 2    |
| 18 | sopot      | dalboset  | 4    | 1    |
| 19 | resita     | sopot     | 2    | 1    |
| 20 | sopot      | dalboset  | 1    | 2    |
| 21 | caransebes | dalboset  | 1    | 3    |
| 22 | calnic     | resita    | 2    | 2    |
+----+------------+-----------+------+------+
```

CODE

```
df1 = df.groupby('Home Team',) ['Htgs', 'Atgs',].rolling(window=4, min_periods=3).mean()

df1 =df1.rename(columns={'Htgs': 'Htgs/3', 'Atgs': 'Htgc/3'})
df1



df2 = df.groupby('Away Team',) ['Htgs', 'Atgs',].rolling(window=4, min_periods=3).mean()

df2 =df2.rename(columns={'Htgs': 'Atgc/3', 'Atgs': 'Atgs/3'})
df2
```

now i need a solution to see the columns with the rolling average next to the Home Team,,,,Away Team,,,,Htgs,,,,Atgs from the original table

Comment: `pd.merge` back on the groupby key, validate many to one.

Answer (score 0):

Done !
i create a new column direct in the data frame like this

df = pd.read_csv('Fd.csv', )

df['Htgs/3'] = df.groupby('Home Team', ) ['Htgs'].rolling(window=4, min_periods=3).mean().reset_index(0,drop=True)

the Htgs/3 will be the new column with the rolling average of the column Home Team, and for the rest i will do the same like in this part.